# How to resolve Scaffold error in flutter project?

Tags: ios, flutter

I've got a strange error message in my flutter project. Message said that problem is with a Scaffold, but i'm sure the problem should be in my Bolc class or somewhere in domain logic, how can I get more detailed error message that will point to the exact problem?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are throwing Scaffold instead of that you have to use **return**.